# Starting Second tab fragment of first activity from second activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, fragmentpageradapter

I am new to android and I am stuck at particular section of the app which I am working on. The problem is - I want to navigate to the second tab of **HomePageActivity** when I perform onClickListener event on  **createEvent**  button in my **SecondActivity**. I tried using solution from various threads here and on other sites too but I was still not able to get my code running.

I also have **RecyclerView** on **HomePageActivity** which is to be populated based on the click event.

Here is the code snippet from both the activities -

**HomePageActivity.java** - Tabbed Activity

```
public class HomePageActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);

        fragmentInfo = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (fragmentInfo != null)
        {
            tabNumber = fragmentInfo.getInt("tabNumber");
        }
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
    }

public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter
    {
        String[] tabList = {"Communities", "Events", "People"};

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm)
        {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position)
        {
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount()
        {
            return tabList.length;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position)
        {
            return tabList[position];
        }
    }
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment
{
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber)
    {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment()
    {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        int viewNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);
        final String[] eventsListArray = {"Event1", "Event2"};

        if (viewNumber == 1)
        {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_communities, container, false);
            TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.communitieslabel);
            textView.setText("communities");
            return rootView;
        }
        else if (viewNumber == 2)
        {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_events, container, false);
            eventsList = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewEvents);
            fab = (FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fab);
            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view)
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(), CreateEvents.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            eventsList.setHasFixedSize(true);
            mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
            eventsList.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
            eventsListAdapter = new RecyclerEventsAdapter(getActivity(), eventListInfo);
            eventsList.setAdapter(eventsListAdapter);
            return rootView;
        }
        else
        {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_peopleprofile, container, false);
            TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.peoplelabel);
            textView.setText("people");
            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
}
```

And the code from the **SecondActivity** -

```
buttonCreateEvent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                String[] eventInfo = new String[0];
                getEventName = editTextEventName.getText().toString();
                getEventDetail = editTextEventDetails.getText().toString();
                getEventLocation = editTextEventLocation.getText().toString();
                while (!getEventName.equals("") && !getEventDetail.equals("") && !getEventLocation.equals("") && !getEventDate.equals(""))
                {
                    eventInfo = new String[]{getEventName, getEventDetail, getEventLocation, getEventDate};
                }
                Intent intent = new Intent(CreateEvents.this, HomePageActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("tabNumber", 2);
                intent.putExtra("openEventFragment", eventInfo);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `getActivity().getIntent().getExtras()` to get a `Bundle` of extras you set in other activity.

Comment: I tried getting intents, but the main thing I am concerned with is how would I **open that specific fragment** with the intent information,i.e., in the PlaceHolderFragment.

Comment: Something like `fragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());`?

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it is making the information to be displayed on all the three tabbed fragments rather than one and it is still opening the first tab after the clickEvent.